# How to divide up a complex workflow into a template of Sub Tasks?

Tags: workflow, project-management, jira, jira-plugin

Our company is moving over to Jira for all project management and issue resolution

We have a few major uses that i am trying to build templates for. One being a typical issue found and fixed and can easily be handled with a single issue with basically the included jira workflow.

A more complex one is following a Waterfall workflow where Requirements are gathered including an estimate. Then Development kicks off, and in parallel test scripts are made. After Development is done the project is tested and handed off to the client. And finally once all is tested we release the change and re-test. In total I have 30 different steps built across 5 Sub-Tasks (However this is all just mapped out in Visio and not actually in jira yet).

The splitting across Sub-Tasks I hope can accomplish 2 things. First is that we want to track open-close times and efforts (hours works and days needed). And we should have the workflow split to multiple people so the Developer can work while a Tester can build their testing plan. That is able to save a few days, however is not a deal breaker.

So a few questions that I hope can help make this possible, although I am quite new to the various add-ons for Jira, I have no idea if we will get everything we want.

1, Is there an add-on that builds templates of Sub-Tasks, since each Sub-Task needs its own workflow. Currently the rules for Jira is to assign a workflow based on Project+Issue Type. So I believe I can have the proper piece of the workflow assigned to each Sub-Task by creating many Issue Types, like "Custom-Dev-Analsys" for the Sub-Task called Analysis

2, Is it possible to have only 1 or a few of all Sub-Tasks being the "current" one? When the issue starts the first Sub-Task should be the only one worked on, with only 1 of the steps being assigned to someone. After sign-off there should be 2 Sub-Tasks, the Development one and building Test Scripts. But all 5 sub-tasks should not be started since the very beginning, but it seems thats what Jira will do. I have looked at the add-on "Structure" and while that has unlimited hierarchy, I do not think it will let the sub-tasks open up in order. There might be a simple way to make the workflow open the next task (I am very new to workflows and trying to learn as much as possible before messing with our site)

3, If anyone can think of some way to do what I need differently, I am all ears.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any plugin that does all what asked for, but I had to deal with similar issues, and managed to sort most of them out with the [Jira Scripting Suite](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/16346), but it did require some development (using python).

It's easy to add to your workflow transitions that will create or close a new issue or a [new subtask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10875414/create-jira-sub-tasks-automatically-when-issue-created/10877552#10877552). I use it to create subtasks just by filling some required fields in one of the issue's screens. After the sub-tasks are created, only the automated scripts can close the issue, and that can be done by closing all of the subtasks.

If this kind of solution suits you I will be happy to help with any further inquires.

Comment: Thank you so much for these details which should cover 90% of the problem (and they look free!)

Answer (score 0):

JIRA doesn't support nested workflows but one useful thing to remember is that if you change the issue type of a JIRA issue, it can have  a different workflow. So an issue could start as TEST-123 which is a Requirement. Then after it reaches the end of its workflow it could be Moved to be a Task issue type. 
Subtasks should stay as before.

Comment: With the prior reply from Kuf it looks like i might do something similar to what you are saying. the issue is created and is part 1, after that finishes the behind the scenes script might create the follow part, and repeat this cycle until done. sadly i think an add on should exist that simple knows how to join workflows and the only thing it does special is clone. i cant imagine it being that hard, but i am not a developer either.